# what do these custom return types do in this example of c#?

Tags: c#, .net, methods

I know that a function with a return type returns the value of the function to the caller of that function.
However, I can't interpret it in practice.

For example:

```
public class InMemoryRestaurantData : IRestaurantData
{
    readonly List<Restaurant> restaurants;

    public InMemoryRestaurantData()
    {
        restaurants = new List<Restaurant>()
        {
            new Restaurant { Id = 1, Name = "Scott's Pizza", Location="Maryland", Cuisine=CuisineType.Italian},
            new Restaurant { Id = 2, Name = "Cinnamon Club", Location="London", Cuisine=CuisineType.Italian},
            new Restaurant { Id = 3, Name = "La Costa", Location = "California", Cuisine=CuisineType.Mexican}
        };
    }

    public Restaurant GetById(int id)
    {
        return restaurants.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == id);
    }

    public Restaurant Add(Restaurant newRestaurant)
    {
        restaurants.Add(newRestaurant);
        newRestaurant.Id = restaurants.Max(r => r.Id) + 1;
        return newRestaurant;
    }
```

In this example it's not clear to me by calling the methods GetById and Add what do the return types do.
I'll appreciate it if anyone describe it to me, please.

Comment: They say "the type of the thing I am returning is a `Restaurant`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not quite describing it right - a function with a return type returns *an object or value of that type* to the caller. So it can work as part of an assignment, i.e.

```
Restaurant x = new Restaurant ();
```

or

```
Restaurant x = GetRestaurantById(1);
```

or

```
Restaurant x;
x = GetRestaurantById(1);
```

So GetById returns a Restaurant object. Can you see any Restaurant objects there?

Even without the Restaurant class definition, you can infer some of the information about what a Restaurant object is from the list in InMemoryRestaurantData - a list of Restaurant objects is being created, each with an Id, Name, Location and Cuisine.

So you can expect that if you declare a new Restaurant variable and use `Restaurant.GetById(1)`, that restaurant object will be Scott's Pizza, and .Location will have Maryland in it, and so on...

Comment: You made it so clear to me by your description. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

When you call GetById passing an id value you are expecting to get back an object of type Restaurant that have that same id.

When you call Add with a new Restaurant you will get back the same object if the add operation is successful.